# Объясните почему данном примере, смещаем результат на min?

Tags: javascript, случайные-числа, alert

```js
var min = 5,
  max = 10;

alert(min + Math.random() * (max - min));
```

Объясните почему `+ min`?

Comment: А вы без него попробуйте, сразу станет ясно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так задача ж сделать генератор между 5 и 10, без +5 который есть минимум вы не получите требуемый результат ведь `Math.random() * (max - min)` = `Math.random() * (5)` и сгенерирует число от 0 до 5. Формула получения результата между двумя значениями:

```
Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: Спасибо,теперь ясно)